Verify whether the Motor Driver has PWM Support
I was looking for a single channel motor driver with a supply voltage range of 6V - 12V and a continuous current range of 2A. I came across a motor driver IC called SS6285L. This motor satisfies the voltage and current requirement I was looking for. My doubt is whether I can control the speed of the motor using PWM. Like can I give PWM signals to "FI" and "BI" pins of the motor driver to control the motor speed in appropriate direction. The link for the website where I found the IC is below.
https://www.lcsc.com/mobile/product-detail/Motor-Driver-ICs_LEADPOWER-SS6285L_C3345075.html
In the above link, it is mentioned that PWM interface is available in this IC.

But I just want to verify that the details mentioned in that website are correct. The datasheet of the IC is below
https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2208031730_LEADPOWER-SS6285L_C3345075.pdf
In the datasheet, the word PWM is used two times. But I can't understand whether it actually talks about the external PWM to control the motor speed.

It will be a great help if someone clarify whether I can use this IC to control the speed of the motor using PWM. Also, does this IC have inbuilt flyback diodes on the output side, or should I add them externally? In the circuit diagram that was given in the datasheet, there were no external diodes. But I just want to clarify that too.

